# DD4T - No proxy type error

Tags: dd4t, 2013-sp1

Getting an intermittent YSOD error on our DD4T website: There is no proxy type for class java/sql/Timestamp.

[image]

Refreshing the page clears the error and our pages work normally.
I'm guessing this is connected the DD4T cache mechanism somehow - has anyone else experienced this error or understand what the JuggerNET exception means (our CD is set up correctly has pages do render)?

We're hosted on an AWS instance running Windows Server 2008 R2 and Java 7.

**UPDATE**
Came across [John's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452177/date-datetime-object-type-in-ambientdataframework) - it smells very similar .... but the published date is coming from Broker and includes a time element. Also, the error seems to be suggesting the JuggerNET framework cant find a suitable .NET class to handle java.sql.Timestamp - is this something I should raise with SQL Support?

Comment: Which jdbc.jar are you using ? Are you sure you have the 2013SP1 dlls in your website app and not by chance the 2011 ones?

Comment: I'm using sqljdbc4.jar. Just checked the Tridion.ContentDelivery.* DLLs and we are using version 7.1.0.* which are Tridion 2013 SP1.

Answer (score 1):

java.sql.Timestamp is the representation in Java of a database TIMESTAMP field; it is a subclass of java.Util.Date for use by JDBC drivers to differentiate the TIMESTAMP database field type.

See [the java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) for more information on java.sql.Timestamp; this appears to be new in Java 7.

Considering this my guess is that somehow JuggerNet doesn't know what the appropriate .Net type is for this Java type which would point to either a bug in the JuggerNet configuration or in JuggerNet itself.

Perhaps it is specifically a problem with the combination of Java 7 and your version of .Net; which .Net version are you using?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Neil, .NET Framework 4.5.2 is not officially supported by Tridion, I don't know if your issue is related to this .net version. Did you try with .net 4.5.1 and see if this issue still exists?

Comment: Which database server and version are you using? I've come across some posts regarding Oracle changing how field types are represented in java code between versions 10 and 11...

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4297.0 (X64)